# AS3 - how to change speed of FLVPlayBack

Tags: actionscript-3, flvplayback

i need to play FLVPlayback Video at different speeds , can i do this by changing frame-rate of FLVPlayBack and how can i achieve this using as3?

Or is there any other method to do the same? Please Suggest me.

Meghana

Comment: Isnt there an in built support in AS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to change the framerate of a video in AS3, it will be always rendered at the video's native framerate.

The only way I can think to do it is to write some sort of function that calculates how to move the playhead, but I cannot guarantee the result of this approach.....

EDIT:
As you ask in your comment, YES, you can do it by controlling the NetStream. Here you have the solution: http://younsi.blogspot.it/2009/03/how-to-play-video-in-flash-in-slow.html

Comment: Richie , can we do that for netStream??

Comment: thanks @Sr. Richeie , for your reply. i guess this will also work fpr increase speed for video. i definitely check this out and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Chiming in a bit late, but there's actually a way to play an FLV in slow motion without constantly seeking or playing/pausing repeatedly. It's just extremely involved.

If you open the .flv file using a URLStream then you can access the bits. Scan for the timestamp, re-write it, then pass the new ByteArray to a NetStream in data generation mode. Using this you can play video at any frame rate - although the ability to play audio in slow / fast motion depends on the codec being used. The layout of an FLV packet is something like:

1. "FLV"
2. packet length
3. packet type (audio / video / metadata)
4. timestamp
5. additional headers
6. data

To change the audio sample rate you would need to muck with the data - much more convoluted than just changing timestamps. I know, for instance, that AAC data has a header which specifies the sample rate as an index into an array:

`[ 96000, 88200, 64000, 48000, 44100, 32000, 24000, 22050, 16000, 12000, 11025, 8000, 7350 ]`

So if you had 44.1 kHz audio (sample rate index = 4) you could play at half speed by declaring the sample rate to be 22.05 kHz (sample rate index = 7)

Answer (score 0):

```
//set your framerate here whatever you want
stage.frameRate = 30;
var FRAMERATE : Number = stage.frameRate;

btnActual.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, videoSpeed);
btn15.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, videoSpeed);
btn5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, videoSpeed);

function videoSpeed (myEvent:Event):void{

    var newFrameRate = Number(myEvent.target.value);    

    stage.frameRate = newFrameRate;

}
```

Comment: thanks @swati for your reply , i tried this but this not seems to work for me :(

Comment: no, changing the framerate is not going to work. Flash will always try to render the video at its native framerate

Comment: For SWF files with video and audio synced to stream, Flash will actually drop your main movie's frame rate to match the loaded SWF video's frame rate.  To keep my main movie running at 60 frames a second, I had to switch to use F4V or FLV files, which are played back at their native frame rates without affecting the frame rate of the main movie.  In both cases, changing the frame rate of the main movie will have no effect on video that's played back.